# Can Llama events call other events?

Tags: llama

I find that I have a number of different "trigger situations", or sets of conditions that trigger an event. So I have an event for each one. But I also find that many of these events have basically the same actions, so **I'm looking for a way to separate conditions from actions.**

1) I have an idea to set up trigger events that only have one action each:, which is to set a Llama variable to a specific value. And then I'll set up action events that each have one of those values as their only condition, and put all the actual actions in there.

2) There are also the OR/AND conditions, where I could build something like:

```
OR
( AND
  ( actual_condition_1
  , actual_condition_2
  )
, AND
  ( actual_condition_3
  , actual_condition_4
  )
)
```

... but that gets ugly fast, and hard to maintain.

**Is there a more elegant method that I've missed?**

Comment: 1) looks quite elegant to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `Application Shortcut` Action, then select Llama as the application.

This gives a list of all the Llama Events, Actions and Profiles and allows you to determine which one to run.